# It is not ... but ... (correct structure)

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say:

> The factor that prevents data from altering is not 'X', but 'Y' and
> 'Z'.

Or as alternative:

> The factor that prevents data from altering is not 'X', but rather 'Y' and
> 'Z'.

The purpose is to say that they are 'Y' and 'Z' which can prevent data from altering, and not 'X'.

```
Note: 'X', 'Y' and 'Z' can be replaced by any word (as a factor).
```

Comment: Your two examples seem to differ only in the word "rather", which, in that context, means approximately "on the contrary".

Comment: There's a jarring parallelism: 'the factor is ... Y and Z'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about how to express a logical relationship in a way that is unambiguously clear.  You are right that there is a kind of clash between the singular noun and the two (and so plural) noun complements.

I would say myself that in the original sentence there is a presumption in favour your intended meaning:  "is not 'X' but '(X and Z)'.

But that presumption does not remove the dissonance or the possibility of misunderstanding.
In the expression there is or ought to be a rule that **where we are dealing with legal, scientific, technical or logical matters, precision trumps brevity and elegance**.  So say **exactly** what you mean.  I do not think the single quotes will do that job.

So I would suggest that you have to say "Y and Z **together**", or "**Y together with Z**"; or, perhaps better still, "**a <or 'the'> combination of** Y and Z".

> The factor that prevents data from altering is not 'X' but the combination of 'Y' and 'Z'.

Comment: I agree, you need either some way to make Y and Z into a singular noun, or drop "factor ... prevents" for a different construction, eg, use because or (yuck!) the passive voice - data are prevented from being altered not by ....